# Isomorphisms for graphs with loops and multiple edges

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I am working with graphs with multiple edges and loops, and I want to eliminate all isomorphic graphs from a long list I've generated. The `FindGraphIsomorphism` function is very nice, but only works for simple graphs. I'm looking to find such a function or its equivalent for multigraphs. For example,

[image: two multigraphs]

Is there possibly a third-party package, or maybe even an external program that would find such graph isomorphisms?

Also, is it possible to compare graphics objects in Mathematica, to see whether they are similar? I have tried `SameQ`, but to no avail.

[image: graphs with self-loops]

I am assuming this is the result because Mathematica plots the graphs with floating-point values, so it is impossible to have two identical graphs like this. So is there a function that looks at the similarity between two graphics objects? I think something like that might do the trick for me in most cases.

Comment: You could replace each edge with an edge-vertex-edge path, converting your multigraph into a unique simple graph which you can compare for isomorphism.

Comment: Clever. I shall give this a go and if successful, make a little wrapper function.

Comment: @Rahul Narain Dang. I was going to suggest that. Now I have to unpat myself on the back.

Answer (score 6):

[IGraph/M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97233/12) 0.1.3 or later supports multigraph isomorphism testing directly. *Note:* Version 0.3.110 fixes important bugs in multigraph (sub-)isomorphism. Upgrade to this release or later.

```
<< IGraphM`

g1 = Graph[{1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4}]

g2 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 4}]
```

As directed graphs they are not isomorphic:

```
IGIsomorphicQ[g1, g2]
(* False *)
```

As undirected ones they are:

```
g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4}]

g2 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4}]

IGIsomorphicQ[g1, g2]
(* True *)
```

We can get a specific mapping like so:

```
IGGetIsomorphism[g1, g2]
(* {<|1 -> 1, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 2 -> 4|>} *)
```

The implementation is based on igraph's support for edge-colored graphs.  Note that at the moment igraph itself (the library underlying IGraph/M) does not support multigraph isomorphism.  It won't error on multigraphs, but it may not give correct results.  It is important to be aware of this when using igraph from R/Python/C.  IGraph/M, the Mathematica interface, does have checks for multigraphs, and can *test* for multigraph isomorphism by transforming them to edge-coloured simple graphs.

There's no builtin implementation for *finding* isomorphisms for multigraphs, but we can do the translation to edge-coloured graphs by hand:

```
asc1 = Counts[Sort /@ EdgeList[g1]]
(* <|1 <-> 3 -> 1, 1 <-> 4 -> 2, 2 <-> 3 -> 2, 2 <-> 4 -> 1|> *)

asc2 = Counts[Sort /@ EdgeList[g2]]
(* <|1 <-> 2 -> 2, 1 <-> 3 -> 1, 2 <-> 4 -> 1, 3 <-> 4 -> 2|> *)

IGVF2FindIsomorphisms[{Graph[VertexList[g1],Keys[asc1]], "EdgeColors" -> asc1}, {Graph[VertexList[g2],Keys[asc2]], "EdgeColors" -> asc2}]
(* {<|1 -> 1, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 2, 2 -> 4|>, <|1 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 2 -> 2|>, 
    <|1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 3|>, <|1 -> 4, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 3, 2 -> 1|>} *)
```

Comment: Is there a way to test isomorphism of Edge-colored  and Vertex-colored multigraphs with IGraphM ?

Comment: The approach given bellow can deal with multi-graphs only non-simple graphs. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @jonaprieto I don't understand what "can deal with multi-graphs only non-simple graphs" means.

Comment: Try a graph with multiple edges and some loops. It won't work or am I missing something? trying to compute Aut(Bn), where Bn is the graph of n-loops and one vertex.

Comment: @jonaprieto Please give a complete example and explain what you mean by "does not work". It's probably best to ask a new question.

Comment: I use Bn=Graph[Table[1 -> 1, n]] as the graph instead of g1 and g2 in your example. Then, I got "VF2 does not support non-simple graphs". $Failed

Comment: @jonaprieto Again, give a *complete* example. I did not use any VF2 functions on non-simple graph in the above post. I can't tell what you are doing.

Comment: @jonaprieto It works here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtJOo.png  You can also post on https://igraph.discourse.group/ if you feel that the question is not appropriate for M.SE. I do need a clear example to be able to help.

Comment: That image is just testing if they are iso. We are interested here to know the set of isos. Anyways, I'm posting a new question for you.

Comment: Check this out: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227903/computing-the-set-of-automorphisms-of-a-non-simple-and-multi-graph