# Automorphism group and its order for a multigraph with loops using IGraph/M (or anything else)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I found this post: 
[How to compute the automorphisms of graphs with multiple edges?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47574/how-to-compute-the-automorphisms-of-graphs-with-multiple-edges)
about how to compute the automorphism group order for a multigraph (labeled and undirected). Even **GraphAutomorphismGroup** in Mathematica version 11.0.1.0 I have cannot handle this problem:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 2}];
g = SetProperty[IndexGraph[g], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
GraphAutomorphismGroup[%]
```

but IGraph/M can, see http://szhorvat.net/pelican/files/IGDocumentation.pdf
or the link above (the answer by @Szabolcs). I'm using IGraph/M version 0.2.1.

QUESTION: How do I find the group order for multigraphs WITH loops such as

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 1, 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 3}];
```

?
Mathematica can do loops (no parallel lines) but the code based on IGraph/M cannot. It fails after this step:

```
rules = Normal@Counts[Sort /@ EdgeList[g]]
Take[#, VertexCount[g]] & /@ 
 IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[{subdivision, 
   "VertexColors" -> Association[colors]}]
```

If it is not possible with  IGraph/M are there other options?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have time to write a full answer now, but one possible solution is to remove the self loops from the graph, construct `subdivision`, then re-add the self-loops to `subdivision`. We should avoid subdividing self loops because they produce more multiple edges, which Bliss cannot handle.

Comment: I'll be happy to wait for whenever you can answer it in detail. I don't understand the what you mean by removing and then adding loops. Adding loops can break the symmetry of the graph ($X$) and decrease the order of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$.  Couldn't a loop be simulated by an attribute given to the vertex (called loop :) )?

Comment: Do you allow multiple loops like in `Graph[{1<->1, 1<->1}]`?

Comment: Yes, both multiple edges and multiple loops.