# IsomorphicGraphQ giving an error when the graphs contain multi-edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks

If I run `IsomorphicGraphQ` on the following graphs, I get an error I don't understand:

```
ga = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}];
gb = Graph[{a <-> b, a <-> b, b <-> c}];
IsomorphicGraphQ[ga, gb]
```

This gives:

> "IsomorphicGraphQ::ngen: The generalized IsomorphicGraphQ[Graph[<3>,<3>],Graph[<3>,<3>]] is not implemented"

The above graphs have multiple edges between the same nodes in them. If I remove these, then the error goes away:

```
ga = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}];
gb = Graph[{a <-> b, b <-> c}];
IsomorphicGraphQ[ga, gb]
```

returns `True`.

Is this really a limitation of `IsomorphicGraphQ` or am I misunderstanding something?

I'm running version 10.0.0.0 on Linux x86 (64 bit).

Comment: An even shorter example that gives the same error message is `ga = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 2}];
IsomorphicGraphQ[ga, ga]`. I'm using 10.0.1 Windows 64-bit. I'm not sure why this occurs; maybe it can't handle multiple edges between two vertices? The documentation doesn't give any examples of multiple-edge graphs, but doesn't say it can't handle them. Strange, does anyone else know what might be afoot here?

Comment: Ray, regardless of this specific problem, you really *should* upgrade to 10.0.2.  It has *lots* of fixes compared to 10.0.0.

Comment: Will do, thanks Szabolcs.

Comment: The answer I provided earlier was incorrect.  Please see [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97127/12) instead.

Answer (score 4):

`IsomorphicGraphQ` and `CanonicalGraph` don't yet support multigraphs (graphs that have more than one edge spanning two nodes). It's a known limitation and I believe it will come in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for the info. By any chance, is this limitation mentioned anywhere in the documentation, or is this undocumented?

Comment: I personally couldn't find it. My source of information is being a WRI employee :)

Comment: The documentation says, "IsomorphicGraphQ works for any graph object including Graph, DirectedGraph, TreeGraph, etc."  This implies that it should work for multigraphs as well.  Could you fix the documentation on this?

Comment: There's an open bug. It should get fixed in the next release.